# XML add new child to each element child of array node

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

I have xml that looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfConfig>
    <Config>
        <!--stuff-->
    </Config>
    <Config>
        <!--stuff-->
    </Config>
</ArrayOfConfig>
```

And I need to populate each `Config` node with a new child, such that it will look like:

```
<ArrayOfConfig>
    <Config>
        <!--stuff-->
        <NewChild>foo</NewChild>
    </Config>
    <Config>
        <!--stuff-->
        <NewChild>foo</NewChild>
    </Config>
</ArrayOfConfig>
```

I have run the following Powershell an an attempt to do so:

```
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load('C:\temp\Configs.xml')
$child = $doc.CreateElement("NewChild")
$child.InnerText = "foo"
$doc.ArrayOfConfig.Config.AppendChild($child)
$doc.Save('C:\temp\Configs.xml')
```

Running this kind of works, it only adds the child node to the second Config.  Example:

```
<ArrayOfConfig>
    <Config>
        <!--stuff-->
    </Config>
    <Config>
        <!--stuff-->
        <NewChild>foo</NewChild>
    </Config>
</ArrayOfConfig>
```

The amount of `Config` child nodes of `ArrayOfConfig` varies, so I can't do any static assignment.  How do I iterate over the children of `ArrayOfConfig` and make sure each of them correctly gets the new child node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load('C:\temp\Configs.xml')
foreach($config in $doc.SelectNodes('//Config'))
{
    $child = $doc.CreateElement("NewChild")
    $child.InnerText = "foo"
    $config.AppendChild($child)
}
$doc.Save('C:\temp\Configs.xml')
```